# RefreshError while trying to access spreadsheet from python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, gspread, oauth2client

I was trying to access my spreadsheet `GetHookedTest` from python following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vISRn5qFrkM) tutorial.
I've added service account successfully and here is my credentials. Shared by sheet with **test@gethooked.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

```js
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "gethooked",
  "private_key_id": "aaaaaabbbbbaaaabbbbaaaaa",
  "private_key": "Private Key here",
  "client_email": "test@gethooked.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "454454554",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/orderplacer%test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreasheets',
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("client_secret.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open("GetHookedTest").sheet1
```

But I'm getting the **RefreshError**

```
six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response.', {'id_token': 'long string'})
```

Comment: For example, when the scopes of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` are removed and `client.open_by_key("SpreadsheetId").sheet1` is used instead of `client.open("GetHookedTest").sheet1`, what result will you get?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you it worked also had a typo in `spreadsheets`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I didn't notice it. But I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. I post it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one method, please try the following modification.

1. Remove the scopes of `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.
2. Use the Spreadsheet ID instead of Spreadsheet name.

   - From

     ```
       client.open("GetHookedTest").sheet1
     ```
   - To

     ```
       client.open_by_key("SpreadsheetId").sheet1
     ```

#### Note:

- From [your reply comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662790/refresherror-while-trying-to-access-spreadsheet-from-python/63664341#comment112578877_63662790), `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreasheets` is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`.